# Json to C# Deserialize Objects nested in Object

Tags: c#, json.net

Im having Json like this:

```
   {  
   "data": {
      "50014992": {
        "value1": "fr",
        "value2": 1378928660,
        "value3": 500149927
      },
     "500149928": {
        "value1": "fr",
        "value2": 1378928660,
        "value3": 500149927
      },
      "50014999": {
        "value1": "fr",
        "value2": 1378928660,
        "value3": 500149927
      },
      "50014991": {
        "value1": "fr",
        "value2": 1378928660,
        "value3": 500149927
      }
    }
  }
```

And i tried to Deserialize it via Newtonsoft Json like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public Data data { get; set; }

    public class Data
    {
        public Dictionary<int, Values> values { get; set; }
    }
    public class Values
    {
        public string value1 { get; set; }
        public int value2 { get; set; }
        public int value3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Deserialisation doesnt throw an error but values is always `NULL`

How do i deserialize multiple objects with different keys nested in another object ?

Comment: Your value class has `val1`, `val2`, `val3` properties. And where are they in your Json data? Nowhere. Your Json data does not have val1, val2, nor val3 properties. What do you expect Json.Net to do; read your mind? ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo Sry thats has just been a typo.  Its fixed now!

Comment: Also, according to your Json, the "data" is the property being the dictionary. But in you class model, this is not the case. In your class model, "data" is an object that has a "values" propery which is the dictionary. Doesn't match your Json data structure (and, as Mark pointed out below, the keys in your Json dictionary are strings, not integers)

Comment: First of all dictionary should be `Dictionary<string, Values>`.... and laso the fields in Values should have exact name as in json, your Data in Json is not a class, it is a Dictionary itself

Comment: @MarkBenovsky I changed the Dictionary and the names are edited since it was just a typo! But it still doesnt work.

Comment: Please read carefuly.. Your `data` in Json is NOT a class, it is a `Dictionary` itself

Comment: @elgonzo Oh... Ok I changed Data to Dictionary... and  now it works ! Thank you so much

Comment: Posted the answer, please accept if it was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure as I cannot test this now. But you should change your `data` type from custom class to a `Dictionary<string, Values>`.

Exactly `string` not `int` because in your Json you have those numbers in brackets, as I remember, Json library wont parse them for you.

So the final class structure should look somelike this:

```
public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, Values> data { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public int value2 { get; set; }
    public int value3 { get; set; }
}
```